# How to perform length check validation under certain conditions using Json Schema Validator?

Tags: json, jsonschema

### I have json schema structure that look like below.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema",
  "description": "My sample Json",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "eventId": {
      "description": "The event Indetifier",
      "type": [ "number", "string" ]
    },
    "serviceType": {
      "description": "The service type. It can be either ABC or EFG",
      "enum": [ "ABC", "EFG" ]
    },
    "parameters": { "$ref": "/schemas/parameters" }
  },
  "required": [ "eventId", "serviceType" ],
  "$defs": {
    "parameters": {
      "$id": "/schemas/parameters",
      "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
      "description": "Other Parameters",
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "activityType": {
          "description": "The activity type",
          "type": [ "null", "string" ]
        },
        "activitySubType": {
          "description": "The activity sub type",
          "type": [ "null", "string" ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

Now I have requirement to perform some validation logic.

1. If eventId == "100" and serviceType == "ABC" then parameters.activityType should be not null and must have a minimum length of 10.
2. If eventId == "200" and serviceType == "EFG" then parameters.activitySubType should be not null and must have a minimum length of 20.

I am trying to perform the validation using "if then else" condition. I am not sure  how to add that inside the Json Schema validator.

Can anyone help me with the syntax?  Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation? https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/conditionals.html#if-then-else

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely possible.  For the first requirement:

```
{
  ...
  "if": {
    "required": [ "eventId", "serviceType" ],
    "properties": {
      "eventId": {
        "const": "100"
      },
      "serviceType": {
        "const": "ABC"
      }
    }
  },
  "then": {
    "required": [ "parameters" ],
    "properties": {
      "parameters": {
        "properties": {
          "activityType": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 10
        }
      }
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

The "required" keywords are there because if the property doesn't exist at all, the "if" subschema will validate as true, which you don't want -- you need to say "if this property exists, *and* its value is ..., then ...".

The second requirement is very similar to the first. You can use multiple "if"/"else" keywords in the schema at the same time by wrapping them in an allOf: `"allOf": [ { ..schema 1..}, { ..schema 2.. } ]`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It works. Is there any way to specify the custom error message that explains which properties are missing. Currently it is not clear from the error message?

Comment: Possibly; you'd have to check the documentation of the evaluator you are using.